# Why is my image not resizing?

Tags: android, image, resize

I have an image path that I decode into a bitmap. I found that that Bitmap is to big and tried to resize it. It didn´t work (the image stayed too big), is my code ok?

```
ImageButton myImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, true);

myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  Are you getting an `Exception` or is it simply staying too big for the frame?

Comment: I have updated my question: it stayed too big.

Comment: You might be better served by a FrameLayout rather than an ImageButton.  Give that a try without changing anything else, and see if it is resized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, true);
myBitmap.recycle();
myBitmap = null;
```

It's designed to not change the original bitmap.  You're not capturing the reference so it's just being thrown away.

Keep in mind that creating a bitmap in this format takes up more memory because you're creating a new bitmap while still holding on to the old one.  If you're doing this very often and not throwing away the old reference, then your heap will grow massive real quick.

Comment: You can make them mutable.  He's just using the static method wrong.  It doesn't change the original bitmap. It creates a new bitmap out of the old one.

Comment: You're right, he would have to create a new instance of the bitmap, rather than a new reference.